# Login form PHP using PDO statements

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I am creating a **signup and login form**. In signup form i am taking inputs from the users and storing those inputs in my database. I want when user input **username** and **password** in **nss-login.php** then it compares from the database whether that username and password is available in database or not. If credentials are available then it redirects to **nss-admin.php**.

However, current code doesn't seem to be working for whatever, everything seems okay logically. I am fairly new to php about two weeks so obviously I'm missing something. I've been looking around to see what I am doing wrong but still can't figure it out, so I am posting here as a last resort. I appreciate you taking the time to view my question.

***Please make the required changes in code files and rectify errors where necessary.***

This is **nss-functions.php**

```
<?php 

include 'nss-config.php';

function connect($config) {

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname='.$config['database'],
            $config['username'],$config['password']);
        $conn -> setAttribute(PDO :: ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $conn;
    }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }

}

function query($query,$bindings,$conn)
{
    $stmnt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmnt->execute($bindings);
    return ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) ? $stmnt : false;

}


 ?>
```

This is **nss-signup.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create a Free Account</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include 'nss-functions.php';
$conn=connect($config);
if (!$conn) die('Problem connecting to db.');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $repass = $_POST['repass'];

    if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($repass)) {
        echo "Please fill all inputs correctly";
    }

    else {

        if($repass == $password) {

            query("insert into users(username,email,password) values(:username, :email , :password)",
            array('username' => $username, 'email' => $email , 'password' => $password) , $conn);

            echo "Your account is successfully created";

        }

        else {
            echo "Fill password correctly";
        }

    }

}
 ?>
<form action="nss-signup.php" method="post">
<h1>Create Your Account</h1>
<p><label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /></p>

    <p><label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></p>

    <p><label for="password">Choose a Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /></p>

    <p><label for="repass">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="repass" name="repass" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="loginform" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is **nss-login.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    include 'nss-validate.php';

    session_start();
     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        if(validate($user,$pass)) {

            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            header("Location:nss-admin.php");
        }

        else {
            echo "Incorrect credentials";
        }

     }
     ?>
    <form action="nss-login.php" method="post">
<h1>Sign in to Your Account</h1>
<p><label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /></p>

    <p><label for="password">Your Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="loginform" /></p>
    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="nss-signup.php">Create one</a>.</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is **nss-validate.php**

```
<?php 

include 'nss-functions.php';

function validate($username,$password) {

    $x = query("select username from users where username = :username", // variable for username
            array('username' => $username) , $conn);
    $y = query("select password from users where password = :password", // variable for password
            array('password' => $password) , $conn);
    return ($username == $x && $password == $y);
}
 ?>
```

This is **nss-admin.php**

```
<?php require 'nss-login.php'; ?>
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Hello, <?= $_SESSION['user']; ?></h1>
 <h3><a href="#">logout</a></h3>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: *"Please make the required changes in code files and rectify errors where necessary."* - We can't do that. What errors are you getting, if any?

Comment: @Fred-ii- : This sentence sounds like we should do our homework.

Comment: @Debflav Not before I've had a minimum of 3 coffees pumped inside me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$conn` does not exist in the variable scope of your `validate()` function.

Change your function definition to this:

```
function validate($username,$password, $conn) {
```

and call it accordingly.

Note: Your validate function is completly useless. It will log everybody in with an existing password of any other user (if works at all, what I doubt). Also, you seem to store the password in plain text in the database.

Comment: *"It will log everybody in with an existing password of any other user"* - So true. OP stands at asking "how" to check it then; so be ready for it ;)

Comment: @Raunak Hajela: Please enable proper error_reporting __now__ – PHP could have told you about the scope issue already.

Comment: Indeed, this error should display a warning message... (+1 for response).